# How do you continue a while loop only if a function has been called?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a Gui game where words are generated and then the user can input an answer. I'm at a point where I need the loop that keeps these words from popping to only run if the word is checked if it's correct.

```
    # Functions
def words():
    global score
    global timer
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start <= 60:
        entry.focus_set()  # Activate the entry box
        word = random.choice(word_list[0])
        word_label.config(text=word)
        # Here should be code that makes it that a new word is only generated if the check word is run


        root.update()

    results(score)

def check_word(event, word, score):
    global wrong
    if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
        score += 1
        entry.delete(0, 9999999)
    else:
        wrong += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), 
I think you could bind a key event into entry box that will call 2 methods:

`root.update()`

`results(score)`

Something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)
    root.update()
    results(score)

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem with that is I need to keep update in the game function for the 60-second timer to go down right?

Comment: Just bind another event handler `<FocusIn>` to start couting when user focus on the entry box